# How can you arbitrarily number subsections in LaTeX2e

Tags: latex

I'm reviewing a textbook, which is divided into chapters and sections. My review used the article document class, and I'm correlating the chapters to sections, and particular exercises to subsections. The exercises are numbered in numerical order for each chapter, so an abbreviated table of contents looks like this:

```
Chapter 1 Introduction to Statistics
  Section 1.1 What is statistics
    Ex 1.1 Exercise one
    Ex 1.2 Exercise two
  Section 2 Descriptive Statistics
    Ex 1.3 Exercise three
    Ex 1.4 Exercise four
  Section 3 Inferential statistics
    Ex 1.5 Exercise five
    Ex 1.6 Exercise six
```

I'm working selected exercises in order to illustrate the points I'm making in my review. I would like to have the section numbering, and the table of contents to look like this, assuming I'm working exercises 1.4, 1.6, 2.20, 2.31, 3.15, 3.25, and 3.42:

```
1. Introduction
  1.4 Exercise four
  1.6 Exercise six
2. Sampling
  2.20 Exercise twenty
  2.31 Exercise thirty-one
3. Probability
  3.15 Exercise fifteen
  3.25 Exercise twenty-five
  3.42 Exercise forty-two
ETC
```

Using LaTeX out of the box, I get consecutive numbering which confusingly gives (as in chapter 3):

```
3. Probability
  3.1 Exercise fifteen
  3.2 Exercise twenty-five
  3.3 Exercise forty-two
```

Using the starred version of \subsection* eliminates subsection numbering altogether. The answers I've found to my arbitrary numbering question are verbose and not satisfactory, in that I have to do a lot of markup to produce the effect that I want. I'd really like a package to do this (perhaps named \usepackage{arbitraryNumberedSubsections}).

QUESTION: Is there an algorithm that will assign arbitrary subsection numbers in LaTeX? Is this algorithm practical and implement-able in TeX or LaTeX? This question is not about debugging, a nonreproducable problem, homework, a third party tool or library, a general computing question, or a professional administrative question.

Thanks, CC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a package that does this (but there may well be one).

You could manually set the (sub-)section number, as in

```
\setcounter{subsection}{3} % one less than what you want
\subsection{Foo}
% --> 4. Foo
```

You can just as well define a new command to wrap that up and use that.  Full working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\nsubsection}[2]{
    \setcounter{subsection}{#1}
    \addtocounter{subsection}{-1}
    \subsection{#2}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
  \nsubsection{4}{Exercise four}
  \nsubsection{6}{Exercise six}
\section{Sampling}
  \nsubsection{20}{Exercise twenty}
  \nsubsection{31}{Exercise thirty-one}
\section{Probability}
  \nsubsection{15}{Exercise fifteen}
  \nsubsection{25}{Exercise twenty-five}
  \nsubsection{42}{Exercise forty-two}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solves the problem --- which I actually simplified a good deal, but with your guidance I created a new command to answer the numbered exercises as I needed. I appreciate your help, and learned more about LaTeX in the process.